# Firebase dataSnapshot retrieving old nonexistent node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was playing with Firebase, removing and adding users.
Then I decided to delete all my users and now I still can access nodes that doesn't exist anymore.
Below is how I'm retrieving the dataSnapshot and a print from my most recent Firebase database.

```
mFirebaseUsersRef = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USERS).child(mLoggedUser.getEmail());

    mFirebaseUsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                mLoggedUser = dataSnapshot.child(mLoggedUser.getEmail()).getValue(User.class);
```

[Firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Eid.png)
Notice that there's only one user on the users list, however if my mFirebaseUsersRef referencies an email that had a node before deleting all my users at my Firebase database, but now doesn't exist, the dataSnapshot will retrieve all the data that existed before deleting the node.
I hope I made myself clear, I will be pleased to answer any doubt about my question.
Below is a print of the nonexistent data that my dataSnapshot is retrieving
[Ghost data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMjO8.png)
EDIT
After debugging each line, I noticed something odd, the dataSnapshot at first exist as shown here: [Ghost data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMjO8.png), but after going through the entire if (even through `startActivity(i);`) it returns to `if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {` and shows that the dataSnapshot is now null: [Now node is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhLB4.png)

Comment: The only way I can think of is that you have disk persistence enabled and the data is being served from there. Any chance that's it?

Comment: Is disk persistence on by default? If so, then this could be the problem, however I didn't implemented this:
`Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

Comment: I think it's off by default. And it would also only cause this behavior if you don't have a network connection. But as said: it's the only explanation that quickly comes to mind.

Comment: The fact that the app reads the if twice, first recognizing the node as existent and then as null should mean something?

Comment: That sounds like the initial event is firing from the local cache and then once the server updates come in it fires a reconciliation event.

Comment: I see, is there a way to prevent the app from receiving the data from the local cache?

Comment: Seems you are working off your local cache, can you confirm you have internet access? Disabling local cache should do the rick : Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setPersistenceEnabled(false);